# Why do my firebase security rules not prevent access in the database emulator with @firebase/rules-unit-testing?

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-tools

To get basic tests done, I set my firebase realtime database rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "false",
    ".read": "false"
  }
}
```

I run `firebase emulators:start` and see all host:port data where the database emulator is running.  Then, I run a simple test:

```
import {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment,
  RulesTestEnvironment,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import assert from "assert";
import { describe, beforeEach } from "mocha";
import { ref, set, get } from "firebase/database";

describe("earth security rules tests", () => {
  let testEnv: RulesTestEnvironment;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
      projectId: "PROJECT_NAME",
      database: {
        host: "HOST",
        port: "PORT",
      },
    });
  });

  it("should not allow read access to all users", async () => {
    const alice = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext();
    const db = alice.database("http://HOST:PORT/?ns=PROJECT_NAME");
    get(ref(db, "/users")).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log("snapshot:", snapshot.val());
    });
    await assertFails(get(ref(db, "/users")));
  });
});
```

The data I imported in the database displays with the console.log inside of the 'get' function, and the result fails with error

> Error: Expected request to fail, but it succeeded.

I know the database emulator is running correctly and whenever I make a change to the rules file, it shows

> ✔  database: Rules updated.

so I think the rules are configured properly.  Why does the test fail?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer comes in two parts.  First, I needed to add a "rules" key to the initialization.  Second, I needed to remove my database url from the call on the context.  I get the first one, but I would be curious if someone know why I needed to remove the url.  The [docs RulesTestContext.database()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/emulator-suite/rules-unit-testing/rules-unit-testing.rulestestcontext.md#rulestestcontextdatabase) include a url. So why does it work without it?

```
import {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment,
  RulesTestEnvironment,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import assert from "assert";
import { describe, beforeEach, before } from "mocha";
import { ref, set, get } from "firebase/database";
import { readFileSync, createWriteStream } from "node:fs";

describe("earth security rules tests", () => {
  let testEnv: RulesTestEnvironment;

  before(async () => {
    //uses .env variable for FIREBASE_EMULATOR_HOST
    testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
      projectId: "PROJECT_NAME",
      database: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 4001,
        rules: readFileSync("database.rules.json", "utf8"),
      },
    });
  });

  it("should not allow read access to all users", async () => {
    const unAuthDb = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext().database();
    await assertFails(get(ref(unAuthDb, "/users")));
  });
});
```